# Set credentials as environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to now, how to use credentials as secure as possible in automation tasks.

In the following post on [medium.com](https://medium.com/coders-do-read/earn-the-fanatic-badge-on-stack-overflow-828d2c46930) the author uses environment variables to store credentials, which he want to use in a python script. On my personal system and for testing purposes I think it is fine to do this temporarly, but on a third party host system from heroku? I got a bit nervous about the idea saving credentials in plane text.

So I was wondering, if where is a solution to set the rights to system environment variables, like I do for my ssh keys as example? Or better: What is the prefered way to work with credentials in a script?

Comment: You're asking us to help you cheat your way to a golden badge?

Comment: I don't need help to set it up. If I want to do it I am perfectly save to achieve it alone. I was more general concerned about the approach from the author by setting up sys env vars with clear text credentials. So I am asking in general for a good/secure approach to handle credentials in automating tasks. My original idea is to handle the rights like I do with files. But I am not shure if this is possible. My second approach would be a password secured ```screen``` session.

Comment: If someone is going to do this in clear text, chances are either security or the site's standing itself, or both are the least of his concerns. Your post may be found inappropriate by many here. Please reconsider it.

Comment: @Cbhihe What changes do you have in mind? I honestly cannot clearly follow your points. Is it just the tittle?

Comment: Given https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/circumvention-of-security-or-policy, I'm OK with the question as it stands. It could be improved by removing the unnecessary reference to "gaming" the Stack Exchange system and focusing on the central issue of security as it pertains to environment variables on third-party systems.